# Test if an html element has a class applied to it?

Tags: angular

I want to ensure that something won't happen if an html element has a class applied. Is there a way to write

```
<div *ngIf="<elementid does not have class x applied>">
```

EDIT: the actual situation is that I have tabs and under some circumstances I have two set to active at the same time. I would like to set one of the tabs to not be active if any of the other tabs are active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using class list https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList.

```
<div #elname class="test"></div>

<div *ngIf="elname.classList.contains('test')">
  This will show
</div>
```

Comment: yes this works thanks! I submitted an edit to fix some missing closing braces also.